# How to add additional attribute on table header on DataTable?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to add additional data attribute on header of my column on Datatable particularly the `<th>`.

Unfortunately, I am having problem on how to inject it on the current parameter definition of column of Datatable. Here is the sample definition of my column:

```
columns: [
      {
        title: "ID",
        createdCell: (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) => {
          $(td).empty();
          $("<button />")
          .attr("type", "button")
          .addClass("btn")
          .addClass("btn-link")
          .html(`${ cellData } (Details)`)
          .appendTo(td)
          ;
        }
```

I can definitely add additional class into thead by using this code:

```
title: "ID",
className: "additional class"
```

But I wonder if I can add additional data attribute like:

```
data-translate
```

Comment: @charlietfl The table data <td> is the one that was modified instead of <th>

Comment: Ahh yes my bad, I missed the *headings* part. The headings are not generated by the plugin so you can modify them the same way you would any other element in a page

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please see https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().header()

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:

```
$('.table thead th:eq(0)').attr('data-translate', 'Info');
```

I am just manually adding the attribute per index count of the column, on this case, the first column.